# What is a return type of a `use` directive?

Tags: typescript, svelte

After reading svelte tutorial I noticed that `clickOutside` function returns an object with a `destroy` method.

What would be the correct return type of a custom `use` directive?

```js
export function clickOutside(node: HTMLElement): ??? { 
    // setup work goes here...

    return {
        destroy() {
            // ...cleanup goes here
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [ActionReturn](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/555cdf3da21fe6dc84c236d8e93b027e44a22808/src/runtime/action/index.ts#L20)

```js
export interface ActionReturn<Parameter = any> {
  update?: (parameter: Parameter) => void;
  destroy?: () => void;
}
```

Available from `import type { ActionReturn } from "svelte/types/runtime/action";`

But instead of the `ActionReturn` i'll suggest using the `Action` type:

```js
import type { Action } from "svelte/types/runtime/action";

const clickOutside: Action<HTMLElement, undefined> = (node) => {
  // setup work goes here...
  return {
    destroy() {
      // ...cleanup goes here
    }
  };
};
```

Because that allows Typescript to verify that the type of the options parameter for the action and the update method are of the same type.

Comment: I just tried to import it and suddenly VSCode suggested me a `SvelteActionReturnType` type which is exactly the same type as you described. Thanks

Comment: `SvelteActionReturnType` is from the svelte2tsx package installed inside VSCode, that might present issues when running `tsc` validation.
But I did find that ActionReturn _is_ exported via "svelte/types/runtime/action" (i'll update  my answer)

Answer (score 1):

The import path has changed since `3.46.6`.

- [4.0.0](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/packages/svelte/CHANGELOG.md#400): Stricter types for Action and ActionReturn (see PR for migration instructions) (#7442)
- [3.46.6](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/packages/svelte/CHANGELOG.md#3466): Actually include action TypeScript interface in published package (#7407)
- [3.46.5](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/packages/svelte/CHANGELOG.md#3465): Add TypeScript interfaces for typing actions (#6538)

It should now be imported from `svelte/action`. Reference [v4 docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action).

```html
<script>
  /** @type {import('svelte/action').Action}  */
  function foo(node) {
    // the node has been mounted in the DOM

    return {
      destroy() {
        // the node has been removed from the DOM
      },
    };
  }
</script>

<div use:foo />
```